# ValueError: Domain error in arguments scipy rv_continuous

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I was trying to sample random variables subject to a given probability density function (pdf) with scipy.stats.rv_continuous:

```
class Distribution(stats.rv_continuous):
    def _pdf(self,x, _a, _c):
        return first_hitting_time(x, _a, _c)
```

where the function *first_hitting_time* is

```
#pdf of first hitting time of W_t + c*t on a. 
def first_hitting_time(_t, _a, _c=0.0):
    return _a/_t*np.exp(-0.5/_t*(_a-_c*_t)**2)/np.sqrt(2.0*np.pi*_t)
```

then I continue with

```
myrv= Distribution(name='hittingtime', a=0.002,b=30.0)
data3= myrv.rvs(size=10000, _a=1.0, _c=0.0)
```

and interpreter starts to complain-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-246-71f67047462b>", line 1, in <module>
    data3= myrv.rvs(size=10000, _a=1.0, _c=0.0)

  File "C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py", line 856, in rvs
    raise ValueError("Domain error in arguments.")

ValueError: Domain error in arguments.
```

it seems if I set `_c` to be some number larger than 0.0, it works fine, but not for `_c` less than 0.

I am a bit confused about this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.html):

> #### Subclassing
>
> New random variables can be defined by subclassing the rv_continuous
>   class and re-defining at least the `_pdf` or the `_cdf` method (normalized
>   to location 0 and scale 1).
>
> **If positive argument checking is not correct** for your RV then you will
>   also need to re-define the `_argcheck` method.

It's not clear to me from your function what `_a` and `_c` represent, but it looks like you want to allow them to be negative.

See the default implementation [in the source of `_distn_infrastructure`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py#L859-L869)

Comment: Do you know why arguments should be positive for rvs? for example for uniform.rvs(). I get the same error, but I don't understand the logic. Thank you.