# What does "ValueError: Domain error in arguments" refer to in stats.truncnorm.rvs?

Tags: python

I am generating random numbers using:

`stats.truncnorm.rvs(a, b, loc=x_avg, scale=x_std, size=size, random_state=seed))`

where

```
a = 33.77325454147516
b = -53.773254541475154 
x_avg = -4.569 
x_std = -0.45690000000000003 
size = 400
seed = 973694259
```

I get `ValueError: Domain error in arguments` error. I was wondering what it refers to. I looked at some previous posts such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39420430/valueerror-domain-error-in-arguments-scipy-rv-continuous), but could not find the issue.

Comment: could it be that `scale` (i.e., `x_std`) must be positive?

Comment: @CrepeGoat, yes, thanks, it is fixed. I chose std as percentage of avg, but did not pay attention to the sign. It is solved now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @CrepeGoat point:

Initially, I chose a negative value for std by mistake (because I chose it as a percentage of average). Changing std to a positive value solved it.